# MiniProfiler - SqlParameter

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-mini-profiler

I am using the latest version of the MiniProfiler, everything is setup and working as I would expect.  My only issue is that SqlParameters are not being displayed.

For example, I am running a stored procedure:-

```
var cmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "USP_Admin_Subscription_List";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// parameters
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserRef", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Value = customerRef });
```

When this executes I see the SQL in the MiniProfiler display but I do not see the Parameter @UserRef nor it's value.

Is this possible?  It would be great to see the value so I can ensure the correct value is being passed.

I am using MVC 3

Any advice would be welcomed.

Cheers,

J

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Old questions, but just in case anyone else is looking for the answer to this:

The sample code has:

```
    // different RDBMS have different ways of declaring sql parameters - SQLite can understand inline sql parameters just fine
    // by default, sql parameters won't be displayed
    MiniProfiler.Settings.SqlFormatter = new StackExchange.Profiling.SqlFormatters.InlineFormatter();
```

You need to change it to:

```
MiniProfiler.Settings.SqlFormatter = new StackExchange.Profiling.SqlFormatters.SqlServerFormatter();
```

And your parameters will appear.